# Find the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)\operatorname{arccot}(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Consider $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(x)\cot^{-1}(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$.

I've tried: $\displaystyle F(a,b) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(ax)\cot^{-1}(bx)}{\sqrt{x}}$, so $\displaystyle F''(a,b) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{a\sqrt{x}(1+b^2x^2)} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{2a(1+x^4b^2)} = \frac{\pi}{2a\sqrt{2b}}$.

So $F'_{a}(a,b) = \frac{\pi}{2a}\sqrt{b}+C(a)$, also we can make for $a$. But how can we find constant?

It's easy to see that $C(a) = 0$, what about $C(b)$? If we consider $F'_{b}(a,b) = \frac{\pi\log(a)}{\sqrt{8b}} + C(b)$ then it isn't easy to find it. Any ideas?

*edit* also I thought about consider $\cot^{-1}(bx)$ and then make a substitution $t = \frac{1}{1+x}$ and represent $\log$ as series

Comment: It seems your integral does not converge.

Comment: @omegadot yeah there must be $arcctg$. But it's doesn't help

Comment: "arcctg" is **not** a standard mathematical notation for a trigonometric function.  Use standard notation.  Either it is $\operatorname{arccot}$ or $\cot^{-1}$ or $\arctan$ or $\tan^{-1}$.

Comment: @heropup sorry in my language it oftener write like $arcctg$

Comment: @heropup but I think , that this's not a **mistake**. Users understand what the main idea.

Comment: The integral does not converge... You cannot differentiate under the integral sign.

Comment: @Galc127 even wolfram shows that integral converges.

Comment: @openspace, my bad, it was written with $\arctan$ whereas it should be $\text{arccot}$...

Comment: @Galc127 , there is a mistake in your integral. My integral consist of $\cot^{-1}$ not $\tan^{-1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a slightly different approach: Consider

$$ I(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan x}{x^{1+s}} \, dx. $$

This integral converges when $s \in (0, 1)$. And for this $s$, taking integration by parts followed by the substitution $x = \tan\theta$ leads to

$$ I(s) = \frac{1}{s}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^s (1+x^2)} \, dx = \frac{1}{2s}\operatorname{B}\left(\frac{1-s}{2},\frac{1+s}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2s}\sec\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right). $$

On the other hand, the substitution $x \mapsto 1/x$ shows that our integral is written as

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log x \operatorname{arccot}(x)}{x^{1/2}} \, dx
= - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log x \arctan x}{x^{3/2}} \, dx
= I'(1/2). $$

Evaluating the derivative, we finally obtain

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log x \operatorname{arccot}(x)}{x^{1/2}} \, dx = \frac{\pi^2}{\sqrt{2}} - 2\sqrt{2} \, \pi. $$

Answer (score 2):

More generally \begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x\cot^{-1}ax}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx\\
= &\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\frac1a}
\frac{\sqrt x\ln x}{y^2+x^2} \overset{y\to y^2}{dy}\overset{x\to x^2}{dx}
=\int_{0}^{\frac1{\sqrt a}} \int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{8y x^2\ln x}{y^4+x^4 }dx\ dy\\
=& \ \frac\pi{\sqrt2} \int_{0}^{\frac1{\sqrt a}} (\pi +4\ln y)dy= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt {2a}}(\pi -4-2\ln a)
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the integral does not converge on $[1, \infty]$ for example, therefore not on $[0, \infty]$:

$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {\frac {\log(x)\arctan(x)} {\sqrt x}} {\frac 1 {\sqrt x}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \log(x) \arctan(x) = \infty$

and since $\int_1^\infty \frac {dx} {\sqrt x}$ diverges, your integral diverges by the second comparison test.

Comment: First of all there is $arcctg(x)$.

Comment: Correct... I don't see your point